# MDRectangleFlatIconButton's text is displayed in two lines when updated with a longer text

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

Program installed in my computer :
python 3.10.4
KivyMD 1.0.0.dev0
kivy 2.1.0.

I want to update MDRectangleFlatIconButton's text. It changes with a new text but when the new text is longer than previous text, then the text fits in two lines. When i use a normal button, the new text fits in one line with proper adjustment.

but Since there is a Icon in MDRectangleFlatIconButton, when a new text is longer than previous text, the text fits in a two line.

To run the program, Add a new app name which is longer than "Info" inside "Info" button's popup window, then click "Update Top Bar's name". Then, it updated title and the text of "Info" button at the front main App.

I have tried to change this by adding button's text_size: self.width, valign:"center", haling: "center", or manually adding text_size: cm(10), cm(10). Also, i tried with on_release: "app.root.ids.bt_information.text_size = self.width, None

but nothing works so far.

I greatly appreciate your help.

When I input a longer App name,"Info12", than previous name which is "Info", then it is displaced in two lines in the button. [This is the result of it](https://drive.google.com/file/d/13PVx6rK7MQO42uQ7vISbIZkdyBioZ9_P/view?usp=sharing)  [image]

Python code
'''

```
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
'''Setting the size of first window for program'''
from kivy.config import Config                 #another way of setting size of window
Config.set('graphics', 'width', '600')         # from kivy.core.window import Window
Config.set('graphics', 'height', '750')        # Window.size = ("600", "750")

from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.factory import Factory
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty

Builder.load_file('new_window_popup.kv')

class Dex(Popup):
    pass
    
class Remi(Popup):
    pass

class Info(Popup):
    pass

class MyLayout(Widget):
    pass
class AwesomeApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        self.title = "My house"
        return MyLayout()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    AwesomeApp().run()
```

'''

kivyfile: new_window_popup.kv

'''

```
#:import Factory kivy.factory.Factory
#:import MDRaisedButton kivymd.uix.button

<Dex>:
    auto_dismiss: False
    size_hint: 1, 1

    title: "Weight-Based Dose Calculator "   
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: (0,1,0,1)
        Rectangle:
            pos:self.pos
            size:self.size
    
    BoxLayout:
        
        orientation: "vertical"
        size:root.width, root.height

        Label:
            text: "Dex 1" 
        Button:
            text: "Close"
            font_size: 24
            on_release: root.dismiss()    
    
<Remi>:
    auto_dismiss: False
    size_hint: 1, 1

    title: "Weight-Based Dose Calculator "   
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: (0,1,0,1)
        Rectangle:
            pos:self.pos
            size:self.size
    
    BoxLayout:
        
        orientation: "vertical"
        size:root.width, root.height

        Label:
            text: "Remi" 
        Button:
            text: "Close"
            font_size: 24
            on_release: root.dismiss()

<Info>:

    appName:appName
    auto_dismiss: False
    size_hint: 1, 1

    title: "Change Info"   
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: (0,1,0,1)
        Rectangle:
            pos:self.pos
            size:self.size
    
    BoxLayout:
        
        orientation: "vertical"
        size:root.width, root.height

        Label:
            text: "What is your App name?" 
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "horizontal"
            
            MDTextField:
                id: appName
                hint_text: "App Name"
                color_mode: 'primary'
                current_hint_text_color: 1,1,1,1
                hint_text_color_focus: 1,1,1,.9 
                line_color_focus: 1,1,1,1
                font_size: '25sp'
                text_color_normal: 1,1,1,.9
                text_color_focus: 0,0,1,.9
                focus: True
                write_tab: False
            Button:
                text: "Update Top Bar\'s name"
                font_size: 24
                size_hint: .8, .2
                # on_release: root.updateName()    
                on_release: 
                    app.title = appName.text
                    app.root.ids.bt_information.text = appName.text
        Button:
            text: "Close"
            font_size: 24
            on_release: root.dismiss()

<MyLayout>
    MDBoxLayout:
        orientation:"vertical"
        size: root.width, root.height
        
        MDRaisedButton:
            text: "Dex"
            font_size: 32
            text_color: 0,0,0,.9
            size_hint: 1,.5
            on_press: Factory.Dex().open()
        MDRaisedButton:
            text: "Remi"
            font_size: 32
            size_hint: 1,.5
            on_press: Factory.Remi().open()
        MDRectangleFlatIconButton:
            id: bt_information
            text: "Info"
            icon: "youtube-studio"
            font_size: 32
            size_hint: 1,.2
            text_size: self.width, None
            md_bg_color: 0.95,0.61,0.73,1
            on_press: Factory.Info().open()
```

'''

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `MDRectangleFlatIconButton` sets the `width` of its contained `MDLabel` based on the initial `text` and never changes that width, so adding text to that `MDLabel` is forced to add more lines. Here is a hack to work around that issue by calculating the needed width and explicitly changing the width of that `MDLabel`:

```
from kivy.core.text import Label as CLabel
class AwesomeApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        self.title = "My house"
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.change_text, 2)
        return MyLayout()

    def change_text(self, *args):
        butt = self.root.ids.bt_information  # this is the MDRectangleFlatIconButton
        label = butt.ids.lbl_txt  # this is the MDLabel of concern
        butt.text += ' qwe'  # change the text of the Label
        
        # calculate the required width
        core_label = CLabel(text=label.text, font_name=label.font_name, font_size=label.font_size, max_lines=1)
        core_label.refresh()
        
        # set the width of the label to hold the new text on one line
        label.width = core_label.width
```

Comment: I appreciate your help. It solves all my problem. But it is hard to understand how you solved it even though i used your code to fix my problem.
My question is "lbl_txt" and refresh(). These property or fuction are what i can't find in kivy documentation. Would you explain where i can fine information about butt.ids.lbl_txt and core_label.refresh(). 
Thank you so much again.  You are a champion.

Comment: You can view the kivy.core `Label` [here](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.core.text.html). Not obvious, but the `kivy.core.text.Label` is the `LabelBase`. And the `lbl_txt` is found by actually examining the `MDRectangleFlatIconButton` code, seeing that it extends `ButtonContentsIconText`, and that the `kv` for that includes the `lbl_txt` id for the `MDLabel`  object.